# replace method python with multiple values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, replace

I have file test.html

```
<p>Just example code</p>
 <div>
   <img src="http:localhost/img1.jpg">
 </div>
<p>Just example code2</p>
 <div>
   <img src="http:localhost/img1.jpg">
 </div>
<p>Just example code3</p>
 <div>
   <img src="http:localhost/img1.jpg">
 </div>
```

and i wanna with test.python replace in file just string with "img1.jpg" to "img2","img3" etc.

```
import string
s = open("test.html").read()
s = s.replace('http:localhost/img1.jpg','http:localhost/img2.jpg')
f = open("test2.html", 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

but program replace all img1 when i wanna replace all string img1 to img2,img3,img[i+1].

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you need is a new file with img1 changed to img1 , img2 , img3 .. so on . The following code should work . You will have to go one line at a time .

```
i=2
with open("test.html")as f ,open("test2.html",'w') as f1:
  for elem in f.readlines():
    if 'http:localhost/img' in elem:
      f1.write(elem.replace('http:localhost/img1','http:localhost/img%s'%i))
      i+=1
    else:
      f1.write(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
s = s.replace('http:localhost/img1.jpg','http:localhost/img2.jpg',1)
```

The third param is the max ocurrences to replace.

You can see it in [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Comment: but what to do when i wanna create loop to do it in one program

Comment: Just wrap this in a loop: `for n in range(s.count("img1.jpg"))` and then replace with `'img%d.jpg' % n`